# Symfony Tactician-bundle Typehints = Missing handler method error

Tags: symfony, type-hinting

I've used the thephpleague/tactician-bundle with Symfony before, but this is the first time I've used it with Symfony 4.* (specifically 4.1.4) and attempted to use a single handler Class for my Application Service.

When I execute a command in the Controller

```
public function postAction(Request $request, CommandBus $commandBus)
{
    $form = $this->createForm(VenueType::class);
    $form->submit($request->request->all(), true);

    $data = $form->getData();

    if($form->isValid()) {
        $command = new CreateVenueCommand($data);
        $commandBus->handle($command);
        return $form->getData();
    }

    return $form;
}
```

... I get the following error:

```
"error": {
    "code": 500,
    "message": "Internal Server Error",
    "exception": [
        {
            "message": "Could not invoke handler for command App\\Application\\Command\\CreateVenueCommand for reason: Method 'handle' does not exist on handler",
            "class": "League\\Tactician\\Exception\\CanNotInvokeHandlerException",
            "trace": [
```

I've seemingly followed the [installation documents](https://github.com/thephpleague/tactician-bundle) for the tactician-bundle and installed it using Flex.  As far as I can tell everything is configured correctly, so I'm unsure what I'm missing in my implementation.

## Implementation

As per the thephpleague/tactician-bundle installation guide I've installed using Flex and the bundle is registered and the config package installed:

```
tactician:
    commandbus:
        default:
            middleware:
                - tactician.middleware.locking
                - tactician.middleware.doctrine
                - tactician.middleware.command_handler
```

After creating the DTO Command Class 'CreateVenueCommand', I created the handler Class:

```
use App\Infrastructure\Domain\Model\VenueRepositoryInterface;
use App\Application\Command\CreateVenueCommand;
use App\Domain\Entity\Venue;

class VenueApplicationService
{
    private $venueRepository;

    public function __construct(VenueRepositoryInterface $venueRepository)
    {
        $this->venueRepository = $venueRepository;
    }

    /**
     * @param CreateVenueCommand $aCommand
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    public function createVenue(CreateVenueCommand $aCommand)
    {
       $aVenue = new Venue($aCommand->getData())

        if ($aVenue === null) {
            throw new \LogicException('Venue not created');
        }

        $this->venueRepository->add($aVenue);

}
```

Then I registered the handler Class as a Service taking advantage of Symfony's autowiring and Tacticians typehints:

```
    App\Application\VenueApplicationService:
        arguments:
            - '@App\Infrastructure\Persistence\Doctrine\DoctrineVenueRepository'
        tags:
           - { name: tactician.handler, typehints: true }
```

So according to the [installation documents](https://github.com/thephpleague/tactician-bundle), typehints work if:

> 1. The method must be public.
> 2. The method must accept only one parameter.
> 3. The parameter must be typehinted with a class name.

Also, and this is specific to my use case:

> If you have multiple commands going into a single handler, they will all be detected, provided they follow the rules above. The actual name of the method is NOT important.

So when I invoke the commandbus in the Controller Class, I'm unsure why I'm getting the error above.

If I change the Command Handler method to:

```
public function handle(CreateVenueCommand $aCommand)
{
```

... then it works fine.  This would seem to suggest that the typehints aren't working as documented.

It seems in this case that **the actual name of the method *IS* important.** ... or I've made some form of error in my implementation ... or I'm misunderstanding the **multiple commands going into a single handler** use case??

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

## Solution

With a big thanks to kunicmarko20 for pointing me in the right direction.

Specifically for my use case I simply needed to use one of Tacticians MethodNameInflector classes, configured in Symfony thus:

```
tactician:
    commandbus:
        default:
            middleware:
                - tactician.middleware.locking
                - tactician.middleware.doctrine
                - tactician.middleware.command_handler
            method_inflector: tactician.handler.method_name_inflector.handle_class_name
```

... then it was simply a matter of naming each Handler method in my Application Service class 'handle{whateverYouLike}Command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://tactician.thephpleague.com/tweaking-tactician/) under 1. is explained how the naming works, if you want to use a different name than in this table you can implement MethodNameInflector Interface and provide a name of the method.